# How do I render HTML from the Viewbag using MVC3 Razor

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, viewbag

I am trying to pass a form element into an MVC3 view by using the Viewbag and simply write the HTML to the page ...

In controller:

```
ViewBag.myData = "<input type=""hidden"" name=""example"" value=""examplevalue"">";
```

In view (I know I could use a helper for the form):

```
<form action="http://exampleurl/examplepage" method="post" id="example-form">
@ViewBag.myData
<input type="hidden" name="anotherexample" value="anotherexamplevalue" />
</form>
```

This renders the myData as text in the HTML i.e.:

```
 &lt;type="hidden" name="example" value="examplevalue"&gt;
```

So my question is how do I get Razor to do the equivalent of older:

```
<%= myData %>
```

and not replace the <>

Thanks
Paul

Answer (score 184, accepted):

Use `@Html.Raw(ViewBag.Mydata)`.

Answer (score 22):

This should do the job

```
 @Html.Raw((String)ViewBag.myData)
```

MSDN: This method wraps HTML markup using the IHtmlString class, which renders unencoded HTML.

You need to be careful with accepting and displaying un-encoded HTML.

Comment: Thanks very much. The HTML will be a payment processor pre-post encryption so should be fine. Thanks