# ViewBag.Message not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have problem in regards my code. My ViewBag.Message is not working and I don't know why it didn't shows up on my page and eventually it does not redirect me to the Index and stuck on my current controller. Here is my code:

**Controller**

```
public IActionResult AddPayments()
    {
        try
        {
            var sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO LoanPayments (LoanID, DateOfPayment, AmountOfPayment, Remarks) " +
            "SELECT lc.LoanID, " +
            " CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE(), 101), " +
            " ISNULL(CAST(((lt.InterestRate/100 ) * lc.LoanAmount) + lc.LoanAmount / ((dbo.fnNumberOfYears(CONVERT(VARCHAR(15), LoanDateStart, 101), CONVERT(VARCHAR(15), LoanPaymentDue, 101)) * 12)  * 2) AS DECIMAL(18,2)), 0), " +
            " 'Loan Ledger Created For ' + CAST(GETDATE() AS VARCHAR(50)) " +
            " FROM LoanContract lc " +
            " INNER JOIN LoanType lt ON lt.LoanTypeID = lc.LoanTypeID ";
            _Context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sqlQuery);

            ViewBag.Message = "Has successfully created payments today.";

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

**View**

```html
<h2>Create Payment</h2>
<span>@ViewBag.Message</span>
<a asp-controller="Payment" asp-action="AddPayments" class="btn btn-primary">Secondary</a>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7756464/how-do-i-render-html-from-the-viewbag-using-mvc3-razor

Comment: Hi @BobSwager I tried it but it doesn't work too... and it seems it didn't render anything in the html.

Comment: You must return view from AddPayments(). Do not redirect it to Index.

Comment: but the index is the main view... I want to view it to the index itself.

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do that ?

Comment: First of all, AddPayments actions is only intended ONLY for action and the index is only intended for viewing only.  So thats why I only need to view the message in the index view cuz I haven't created a view for AddPayments.

Comment: Well, two things -> RedirectToAction first parameter is the action so it's normal for  you to be stuck in the same controller, you need to specify the controller as a second parameter. In addition - ViewBag does not "live" after a redirect, you should use TempData instead.

Comment: read this article http://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/mvc/viewdata-vs-viewbag-vs-tempdata-vs-session for difference between ViewData,ViewBag,Tempdata and Session if ViewData is also not working then use Tempdata it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use TempData instead of ViewBag and it will persist over the redirect...  but as people have pointed out in the comments - this is a bad idea, and you should refactor your code to avoid having to do this...

Better idea would be to pass the message as a RouteValue to the index view, but again this is not very clean so I would refactor if I were you...

Edit (Simplified example):

```
public IActionResult AddPayments()
    {
        try
        {
            ... // Omitted

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { message = "Has successfully created payments today.");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {    
            throw;
        }
    }

    public IActionResult Index(String message)
    {
        return View((Object) message);
    }
```

And then in your Index view - you do @Model to show the message.

Note: Ideally you would wrap this in a ViewModel instead of just passing the bare string but hopefully this gives you the right idea?

Comment: can post out some references or sample code to implement refactor? That would be a great help!

Comment: @AlvinQuezon See edit. Simplified as not time for full one but hopefully you see idea