# How to prevent Ajax from removing special characters while constructing a url?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, viewbag

I have an `Ajax` function that calls a get request.  I am constructing the url by using data values from `ViewBag`, for some reason am not understading `Ajax` keeps on removing the values from the special character to the end.
This is my Ajax

```
 $.ajax({
      url: 'api/getProvinceDatByUserID/@ViewBag.reportinPeriod&UserId=@ViewBag.userId&provinceName=@ViewBag.provinceName',
      type: 'GET',
      success: function (data) {}
});
```

The expected url should look like

```
api/getProvinceDatByUserID/Jun-2022&UserId=f8f61c2e-6cf3-454f-b3bd-bf6deae205a4&provinceName=ZAMBÉZIA
```

but Ajax trims the provinceName to

```
api/getProvinceDatByUserID/Jun-2022&UserId=f8f61c2e-6cf3-454f-b3bd-bf6deae205a4&provinceName=ZAMB&
```

hence my requesting failing,

How can I set `Ajax` to stop trimming and removing the special values and characters after it? Any help is appreciated

**Update 1**

I have to add the `encodeUri` still same trimming

```
url: 'api/getProvinceDatByUserID/@ViewBag.reportinPeriod&UserId=@ViewBag.userId&provinceName='+encodeURI('@ViewBag.provinceName')
```

**Update 2**

After adding `encodeURIComponent` to the url am no longer getting `ZAMB&` but am getting `ZAMB&#xC9;ZIA`. Does ajax understand What is the `ZAMBÉZIA` the symbol ontop of letter E ?

Comment: Try using `encodeURI`

Comment: Hi @firstlast i have tried that,  still trimming

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7756464/how-do-i-render-html-from-the-viewbag-using-mvc3-razor

Comment: You've misidentified the problem. It occurs long before Ajax gets involved. Viewbag is encoding the string as HTML but you are inserting it into a URL in JS not into HTML. You need to encode the string as a URL component (how you do that in viewbag, I've no idea, I've never used it).

Comment: encodeURIComponent

Comment: Hi @Quentin, am passing it correctly, that is how am accessing the userid and date. 

@ITgoldman am getting this now `ZAMB&#xC9;ZIA`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is how I finally solved by issue

```
 var provinceName = @Json.Serialize(ViewBag.provinceName);
```

then access the variable with the preserved special characters.
and the final url looks like

```
 url: 'api/getProvinceDatByUserID/@ViewBag.reportinPeriod&UserId=@ViewBag.userId&provinceName='+ provinceName ,
```